# Recursive mergesort only sorts half of an array

Tags: java, recursion, mergesort

I am attempting to implement a recursive merge sort algorithm to sort a simple array of integers but I am getting weird values for the indexes in the second half of my array. The first half seems to sort fine which is confusing given that its implemented recursively. The array of random integers is initialized in my main method.

```
public class MergeSort {

public static int Rounds = 1;
public static void MergeSort(Comparable[] ToSort, Comparable[] temp, int first, int last) {
    if(first < last) {
        int mid = (first + last) / 2;

        //Test Block
        System.out.print("For Round " + Rounds + ":\n");
        System.out.print("first = " + first + "   mid = " + mid + "   last = " + last + "\n");
        Rounds++;
        System.out.print("Array in Round " + (Rounds - 1) + " = {");
        for(int i = 0; i <= ToSort.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(ToSort[i]);
            if(i < ToSort.length - 1)
                System.out.print(", ");
            else {
                System.out.print("}\n\n");
            }
        }

        MergeSort(ToSort, temp, first, mid);
        MergeSort(ToSort, temp, mid + 1, last);
        Merge(ToSort, temp, first, mid + 1, last);
    }

}

public static void Merge(Comparable[] ToSort, Comparable[] temp, int first, int mid, int last) {
    int beginHalf1 = first;
    int endHalf1 = mid - 1;
    int beginHalf2 = mid;
    int endHalf2 = last;
    int index = first;
    int Elements = (last - first) + 1;

    while(beginHalf1 <= endHalf1 && beginHalf2 <= endHalf2) {
        if(ToSort[beginHalf1].compareTo(ToSort[beginHalf2]) < 0) temp[index++] = ToSort[beginHalf1++];
        else temp[index++] = ToSort[beginHalf2++];
    }

    while(beginHalf1 <= endHalf1) temp[index++] = ToSort[beginHalf1++];
    while(beginHalf2 <= endHalf2) temp[index++] = ToSort[beginHalf2++];
    for(int i = 0; i < Elements; i++, last--) ToSort[last] = temp[last];

}
```

}

This produces the following output:

UNSORTED ARRAY = {15, 9, 12, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}
For Round 1:
first = 0   mid = 4   last = 9
Array in Round 1 = {15, 9, 12, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}

For Round 2:
first = 0   mid = 2   last = 4
Array in Round 2 = {15, 9, 12, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}

For Round 3:
first = 0   mid = 1   last = 2
Array in Round 3 = {15, 9, 12, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}

For Round 4:
first = 0   mid = 0   last = 1
Array in Round 4 = {15, 9, 12, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}

For Round 5:
first = 3   mid = 3   last = 4
Array in Round 5 = {9, 12, 15, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}

For Round 6:
first = 5   mid = 7   last = 9
Array in Round 6 = {9, 12, 15, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}

For Round 7:
first = 5   mid = 6   last = 7
Array in Round 7 = {9, 12, 15, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}

For Round 8:
first = 5   mid = 5   last = 6
Array in Round 8 = {9, 12, 15, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}

For Round 9:
first = 8   mid = 8   last = 9
Array in Round 9 = {9, 12, 15, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87}

Comment: Then perhaps the "the other half" sorting was not sorted or merged. Step through with a debugger.

Comment: Your MergeSort is ok, your output is ok, what exactly is wrong? Please, show us the input with the wrong corresponding output

Comment: "I am getting weird values for the indexes in the second half of my array." what does that mean?

Comment: @DAle His/her mergesort is ok?! What?! Do you know what's a merge sort?

Comment: @nbro, yes, I suppose that I know what is a mergesort, this is a top-down implementation.

Comment: @DAle Are you sure this a correct top-down implementation?

Comment: @nbro, I'm not 100% sure, but I don't see any mistakes and it works correctly on my tests

Comment: When I said weird values I meant the values for the first, mid and last. And the last array is the "sorted" array the algorithm returns. Obviously, its not sorted. I attempted to step through with a debugger and could not find the problem.

Comment: @user8701934, your last output is before the last `Merge` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mistake in your implementation. If you print your array after applying `MergeSort` method, it is sorted:

```
Comparable[] a = new Comparable[]{15, 9, 12, 19, 49, 43, 57, 70, 78, 87};
Comparable[] b = new Comparable[a.length];
MergeSort.MergeSort(a, b, 0, a.length - 1);

for (int i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++) {
    System.out.print(a[i]);
    if (i < a.length - 1)
        System.out.print(", ");
    else {
        System.out.print("}\n\n");
    }
}
```

will print `9, 12, 15, 19, 43, 49, 57, 70, 78, 87}`

Comment: That is not the case when I run the program. Only the first half is sorted.

Comment: your implementation leaves the array to sort, sorted after the `MergeSort` method is applied, if you print it: 9, 12, 15, 19, 43, 49, 57, 70, 78, 87. I do not see the problem.